# Miracast: Ubuntu 18.04 > SmartTV

Tags: 18.04, screen

I own a SmartTV from Thomson that supports "Miracast" for "Screen Mirroring", and I have successfull tested it on Android-Device.

Now my question is what software I need in Ubuntu 18.04 to mirror the screen + sound from Linux to SmartTV.

Unfortunately, I have not found anything on this.

Answer (score 9):

There's Miraclecast,

https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast

https://launchpad.net/~thopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/miraclecast

And instructions / a discussion from a few years back... I do not know if this has become more user friendly since, or not.
https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast/issues/4

I looked into this a while back when I got a "smart tv", and ended up making the the lazy decision to buy a chromecast device instead.

Comment: Thank you, i think its better to use chromecast too, do you stream over the browserplugin (chrome) with chromecast, is there a possiblity to stream desktop including sound?

Comment: I've been casting from Chrome browser. There's mkchromecast http://mkchromecast.com/ (should be installable form ubuntu repositories), maybe that would do what you want, I have not tried it.

Answer (score 1):

2021. Plex as an app on my Hisense TV, so I installed plex server on my Ubuntu 18.04 PC and works 100%.

Comment: provide more info please about the app and how to  install it and whether it works for other brands too?

Comment: The link is https://www.plex.tv/media-server-downloads/. I cannot say for any other brand of TV, but if you see Plex in the TV's Apps there it will work.

Answer (score 0):

*The easiest and user-friendliest options are probably:*

1. Test the build-in "Cast..." functionality in the Chromium browser or ...
2. Install [MkChromecast](https://mkchromecast.com/) directly from the official Ubuntu 18.04 ppa:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mkchromecast

   mkchromecast
   ```

Comment: This solution is not compatible with Miracast

Comment: OP is asking for a solution that is similar to the Android connection, which works without additional hardware.