# Is it possible to connect to a EzMira powered AnyCast device with Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, display, screen, airplay

I've been trying to connect via Gnome Network Displays, but it keeps timing out when attempting to connect to the device.

Is there any known solution for screen sharing with Ubuntu on a EzMira-powered AnyCast/Miracast device?

Comment: Would any of [these solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038562/miracast-ubuntu-18-04-smarttv) work maybe...?

Comment: Not so far, no.